# Why It gives tree conflicts even though the file is exists in both places in merge?

Tags: merge, tortoisesvn, tree-conflict

I am going to do a TotoiseSVN merge. Branch that i am going to merge from has been **renamed** recently. **Some of the files in that branch have been changed after the renaming**. When i perform a test merge it shows me tree conflicts **only for those files**. But when i really do the merged, it merges correctly and no conflicts can be seen. 
Can any one help me to understand this behavior?

[image: How to select merge]

[image: Test merge window]

You can see the conflicted file in red color, But in the real merged we can't see this.

[image: Tree conflict, You can seen in red color]